# Decompressing a gzipped http response

Tags: java, gzip

Hello fellow java developers. I receive a response with headers and body as below, but when I try to decompress it using the code below, it fails with this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Not in GZIP format
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Server: Jetty(6.1.x)
▼       ═UMs¢0►=7┐ép?╙6-C╚$╢gΩ↓╟±╪₧∟zS╨╓╓♦$FÆ╒÷▀G┬╚╞8N≤╤Cf°►╦█╖╗o↨æJÄ+`:↓2
♣»└√S▬L&?∙┬_)U╔|♣%ûíyk_à\,æ] hⁿ?▀xΓ∟o╜4♫ù\#MAHG?┤(Q¶╞⌡▌Ç?▼ô[7Fí¼↔φ☻I%╓╣Z♂?¿↨F;x|♦o/A╬♣╘≡∞─≤╝╘U∙♥0☺æ?|J%à{(éUmHµ %σl┴▼Ç9♣┌Ç?♫╡5╠yë~├╜♦íi♫╥╧
╬û?▓ε?╞┼→RtGqè₧ójWë♫╩∞j05├╞┘|>┘º∙↑j╪2┐|= ÷²
eY\╛P?#5wÑqc╙τ♦▓½Θt£6q∩?┌4┼t♠↕=7æƒ╙?╟|♂;║)∩÷≈═^╛{v⌂┌∞◄>6ä╝|
```

**Code:**

```
byte[] b=  IOUtils.toByteArray(sock.getInputStream());

ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

String readed;
while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("read:  "+readed);
}
```

Please advise.

Thanks,

Pradeep

Comment: what is `sock` ? If it is a socket, you should know that the headers and some other stuff are not gzipped. Only the response body is.

Answer (score 2):

The MIME header is NOT in the GZIP format, it's in plain text. You have to read that first before you can decompress the stream.

Also, why not just use this:

```
InputStream in = sock.getInputStream();
readHeader(in);
InputStream zin = new GZIPInputStream(in);
```

Comment: can you tell me what you mean by reading a header please readHeader(in); ?

Comment: I mean that when you get a file you'll get a header that says stuff like "Content-type: text/html" which contains metadata in plain text. Each metadata element is separated by a newline, and the whole header ends with 2 newlines, then the data starts. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME_headers

Answer (score 1):

There are libraries for all of this. You can use, for example, [Apache HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/), or you can read its open source to see what it does. At very least, read [the relevant specification.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230)

Answer (score 0):

I second bmarguiles' answer.

Only the *body* (`response-body` in the RFC) is compressed, so you only need to decompress the part that is after the `\r\n\r\n`.

Generally speaking, you can cut the response in half by that double CRLF, and only decompress the second half.